# Why isn't sbt picking up my publishLocal artifacts?

Tags: scala, sbt

So I'm working on this library, which I publish with:

```
sbt publishLocal
```

This is fine (sbt 1.7.3). It shows that it put the artifacts (properly named) into my ~/.ivy2 directory.  Looking through there, all appears to be in order: files, timestamps, etc.

Now I go to another project that will consume this library, set the matching version in libraryDependencies, then delete my target directory for good measure.  I do an `sbt update`, then compile my project.

No library resolve errors--it found the library--but... I added a new method to one of the classes in the library and when my code tries to use it, I get a compile error that this method is not there.  Indeed, I break out old-school Java reflection and dump out a list of all the methods in that library class, and my new method isn't there!

I've triple-checked the version number and it matches the version output during publishLocal.  For good measure I've even set COURSIER_TTL=0s.  No dice.

Why isn't my latest library, with new code, being picked up?

Comment: Did you do a `clean;reload;compile` on the other project after changing the library version?

Comment: could you show each `build.sbt`, the commands and outputs you tried? Is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I'd open the project in an IDE and look which JAR pops up when I "go to symbol" on the modified class. That would help figure out what is the current state, and from there I could hypothesize how I it got there.